# Setting a php variable to html

Tags: php, html

I am setting the value of a php variable to some html. i.e.

```
$_img = '<a href="some url">hehehehehe</a>';
```

The variable is then shown in html after a br tag. But it doesn't execute the html in it. Rather it displays it like `<a href="some url">hehehehehe</a>`. So, is there any problem in my code! How can i do this thing?

Here is the code that displays that IN HTML,

```
 <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?> <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?> <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that renders the variable? Sounds like it's being HTML encoded.

Comment: How do you output the variable?

Comment: The problem is in how you output the variable, and you haven't show us that code.

Comment: @Zathrus, I think when MJQ says "doesn't execute the html" he means that the HTML is not being treated as HTML by the browser, but instead is being displayed verbatim by the browser.  I agree with other comments, that how the variable is rendered / output into the HTML is probably the issue

Comment: yup, I understood that after I read those comments... just forgot to take my comment out :)

Comment: Here is the code that displays that <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
                <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

Comment: @MJQ: Please edit the question to show that code.  Not everyone reads all the comments, especially once they don't all show by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment....

> Here is the code that displays that `<?php if ($_item->getComment()):
>   ?> <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(),
>   array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?> <?php endif; ?>`

As predicted by many people, it looks like you are encoding the value when you display it.

I don't know what the `$this->escapeHtml` function is doing exactly, but it would appear to be doing an HTML Encoding on the string.

The result being that any tag, for example `<a>` will be sent to the browser as `&lt;a&gt;` which the browser will **display** as `<a>`.  The browser will **not** see it as a tag, and will therefore not treat it as one.

So the simple answer is: don't encode the HTML...

```
<?php echo $_item->getComment(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
    $string = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Hehehe</a>';
    echo $string;
?>
```

This works fine! The html is 'executed' and the link is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are just echoing the variable.

You need use the 'htmlspecialchars' method such as below.

```
    <?php
    $new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
    echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
    ?>
```